# Google Analytics Tracking Error - Unrecognized Positional Argument

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I added 2 custom dimensions to Google Analytics and updated my tracking code to support the change.

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-48282121-1', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
    ga('send', 'dimension1', 'https://dryaker.com/Info/AboutUs');
    ga('send', 'dimension2', 'DirectTraffic');
    ga('send', 'dimension3', '');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I'm not seeing the data from my custom dimension in Google Analytics reports. I ran the Google Analytics Debug extension and now seeing a "Unrecognized Positional Argument" warning/error after each customer dimension being sent.

See screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzHGw.png

Ignore the "User has opted out of tracking. Aborting hit." message. On the specific server I'm on, it blocks GA at the IP-level. We have this GA code deployed across 15 sites and seeing the same issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to send those dimensions as hit types instead of setting them on the tracker object.

The send method takes the following signature:

```
ga('send', typeType, optionalHitFieldOverrides);
```

So in your code, you are trying to send a hit of type "dimension1", "dimension2", and "dimension3", and those are not valid hit types.

To fix the problem change the following code:

```
ga('send', 'dimension1', 'https://dryaker.com/Info/AboutUs');
ga('send', 'dimension2', 'DirectTraffic');
ga('send', 'dimension3', '');
```

To this:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'https://dryaker.com/Info/AboutUs');
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'DirectTraffic');
ga('set', 'dimension3', '');
```